# Answer a closed question

Tags: bug, closed-questions

I was redacting an answer and the question get closed: [C# function's return value obtained within an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461856/c-sharp-functions-return-value-obtained-within-an-if-statement)

Out of curiosity, I just removed the `disabled="disable"` attribute from the <kbd>Post Answer</kbd>. Clicked. And **the answer get published**.

Even if this behavior doesn't occur (at least I hope) too often, I think that the front-end JS blocking is far from enough...

Comment: This is probably due to the grace period where answers are still allowed to go through for a short period of time after the question was closed to avoid people losing the time and effort they put into said answer.

Comment: From what I remember, there's something like a four hour grace period on the server, for posters who don't get the "this question is closed" update and therefore can still submit the answer a while later.

Comment: @KevinB I didn't know about this grace period. Anyway, front-end validation isn't enough.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub We're not going to store extra information on the server just to track whether or not the user is allowed to submit the answer after closure. If this becomes a problem, it'd be far more likely that we just got rid of the grace period all together. But it's *not* a problem.